# Can't declare number type in Julia

Tags: julia

According to http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/, one should be able to do this:

```
julia> Float32(-1.5)
-1.5f0
```

Instead, I get:

```
julia> Float32(-1.5)
ERROR: type cannot be constructed
```

This happens for all other attempts to use this syntax, e.g. `x = Int16(1)`

I'm on 0.3.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on 0.3.10 but reading the manual for 0.5. In the manual for 0.3 http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.3/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/

```
Values can be converted to Float32 easily:

julia> float32(-1.5)
-1.5f0

julia> typeof(ans)
Float32
```